# PHP replace text in variable

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

`$image` variable gives this code (when `echo` is used):

```
<img src="/image.png" width="100" height="147" alt="" class="some_class" />
```

- `width`, `height`, `src` and `class` 
  attributes can be different.

What should we do:

1. **remove** `width` and `height` from `$image`
2. replace `alt=""` with `alt="Poster"`

Thanks.

Comment: Are the widht/height incorrect or why do you want to remove them?

Comment: Why do you have markup stored inside a variable?

Comment: They *break* your JS code? How so?

Comment: Too much questions, anyone can just give a right code?

Comment: @Happy: Doubtful, it's not proper to remove parts of HTML in PHP, only insert things into it. Why don't you find the HTML and remove the width and height attributes and set an ALT? You don't need PHP to do that for you.

Comment: Its a part of cms, code goes from core, so I can change just the final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use regular expressions to do this.

```
// Replace width="..." and height="..." with nothing
$variable = preg_replace('/(width|height)\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/i', '', $image);

// Replace alt="..." with alt="Poster"
$variable = preg_replace('/alt\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/i', 'alt="Poster"', $variable);
```

This method is not dependant on the order of the attributes, which of the some other answers are. Also note that the second regular expressions will replace `alt="<any string here>"` with `alt="Poster"`. It should be easy enough to change it to only replace `alt=""` though.

Answer (score 1):

If the attributes can be variable, then your best choice for working with the HTML is to use a library that actually understands HTML, like [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($variable);
$dom->documentElement->removeAttribute('width');
$dom->documentElement->removeAttribute('height');
$dom->documentElement->setAttribute('alt', 'poster');
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

outputs:

```
<img src="http://site.com/image.png" alt="poster"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! 1) with and height can be different. 2) replacement for alt doesn't work

Comment: I'd suggest `'width="100" height="147" alt=""'` since there are going to be 2 alt's after your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/alt="" width="\d+" height="\d+"/i';
$replacement = 'alt="Poster"';
$variable = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $variable);
```

fix to work with any order of attributes(Gordon's comment):

```
$pattern = '/alt=""/i';
$replacement = 'alt="Poster"';
$variable = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $variable);
$pattern = '/width="\d+"/i';
$replacement = '';
$variable = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $variable);
$pattern = '/height="\d+"/i';
$replacement = '';
$variable = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $variable);
```

Comment: this assumes the attributes will always appear in that order.

Comment: what if the attributes appear with more whitespace inbetween e.g. `alt = "" width= "100"    height= "147"`?

Answer (score 0):

will also replace `<embed width="x">` which is wrong. We need to catch only with `<img>` tag